# How could I achieve sending emails in Symfony2/SwiftMailer service with the following criteria?

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer, doctrine-query

I'm trying to achieve a task which is killing me! 
I can only get an ugly message back without success!
Look below my two simple classes....which they pretend through a form in my app to send emails selecting the persons in my DB according to two criterias inserted through the metioned form(products and city).

What should be the possible reasons of this error:

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT u0_.email AS email0 FROM userInfo u0_ WHERE u0_.city = ? AND u0_.products = ? LIMIT 1' with params [{}, {}]:
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Quotera\EmailBundle\Entity\Email could not be converted to string  

    public function EmailAction(Request $request){
        $email = new Email();

        $form = $this->createForm(new EmailType());
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->submit($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

     $city = $email->setCity($form->get('city')->getData());       
     $product =$email->setProduct($form->get('product')->getData());

                $user = $this->getUser();
                $email->setOwner($user);
                $email->setName($user);
                $email->setCity($form->get('city')->getData());
                $email->setProduct($form->get('product')->getData());
                $email->setMessage($form->get('message')->getData());
                $email->setEmail("exellent@sometoon.com");          
                $email->setEmailTo($this->sendEmailsToProviders($city, $product));
                $email->setTime($form->get('time')->getData());
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($email);
                $em->flush();
                $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject($form->get('product')->getData())
                    ->setFrom('exellent@sometoon.com')
                    ->setTo($this->sendEmailsToProviders($city,$product))
                    ->setCharset('utf-8')
                    ->setContentType('text/html')
                    ->setBody('Thank you', 'text/html');
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your quotation has been sent' );

            }
        }
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );

    }

    public function sendEmailsToProviders($city, $product)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $emails = $qb->select('u')->from('UserBundle:userInfo', 'u')
            ->select('u.email')
            ->andWhere('u.city = :city')
            ->setParameter('city', $city)
            ->andWhere('u.product = :product')
            ->setParameter('product',  $product  )
            ->setMaxResults(5)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();


        if(!$emails){
           throw new NotFoundHttpException('Sorry, no Providers with that criteria!');
        }
        return $emails; }





If I  var_dump($this->sendEmailsToProviders('Berlin','Butter' )) ; I get this result

array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'iancasillasbuffon@gmail.com' (length=27)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'iancasillasbuffon@gmail.com' (length=27)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'eddynvg@hotmail.com' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'dolphin23@dolphin.net' (length=21)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'email' => string 'dolphin@dolphin.org' (length=19) 


     <?php

namespace Quotera\EmailBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Quotera\UserBundle\Entity\User;



   /**
    * Email
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="quottum_email")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Quotera\EmailBundle\Repository\EmailRepository")
    * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
    *
    */
    class Email
    {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quotera\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $owner;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tracking", type="integer")
 */
private $tracking;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $ip;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quotation_sender", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $quotationSender;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message_id", type="integer")
 */
private $messageId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
 */
private $quantity;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="qty_type", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $qtyType;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

private $temp;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email_to", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $emailTo;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="captcha", type="string",  nullable=false)
 */
private $captcha;


/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $time;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param User $owner
 */
public function setOwner(User $owner)
{
    $this->owner = $owner;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner;
}


/**
 * @param mixed $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}



/**
 * Set tracking
 *
 * @param integer $tracking
 * @return Email
 */
public function setTracking($tracking)
{
    $this->tracking = $tracking;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tracking
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getTracking()
{
    return $this->tracking;
}

/**
 * Set quotationSender
 *
 * @param string $quotationSender
 * @return Email
 */
public function setQuotationSender($quotationSender)
{
    $this->quotationSender = $quotationSender;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get quotationSender
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQuotationSender()
{
    return $this->quotationSender;
}

/**
 * Set product
 *
 * @param string $product
 * @return Email
 */
public function setProduct($product)
{
    $this->product = $product;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get product
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->product;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return Email
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set category
 *
 * @param string $category
 * @return Email
 */
public function setCategory($category)
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get category
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}

/**
 * Set message
 *
 * @param string $message
 * @return Email
 */
public function setMessage($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get message
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMessage()
{
    return $this->message;
}

/**
 * Set messageId
 *
 * @param integer $messageId
 * @return Email
 */
public function setMessageId($messageId)
{
    $this->messageId = $messageId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get messageId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getMessageId()
{
    return $this->messageId;
}

/**
 * Set quantity
 *
 * @param integer $quantity
 * @return Email
 */
public function setQuantity($quantity)
{
    $this->quantity = $quantity;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get quantity
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getQuantity()
{
    return $this->quantity;
}

/**
 * Set qtyType
 *
 * @param string $qtyType
 * @return Email
 */
public function setQtyType($qtyType)
{
    $this->qtyType = $qtyType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get qtyType
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQtyType()
{
    return $this->qtyType;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return Email
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param string $image
 * @return Email
 */
public function setImage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return Email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set emailTo
 *
 * @param string $emailTo
 * @return Email
 */
public function setEmailTo($emailTo)
{
    $this->emailTo = $emailTo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get emailTo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmailTo()
{
    return $this->emailTo;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $ip
 */
public function setIp($ip)
{
    $this->ip = $ip;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIp()
{
    return $this->ip;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $captcha
 */
public function setCaptcha($captcha)
{
    $this->captcha = $captcha;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCaptcha()
{
    return $this->captcha;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private  $path;


public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'images/products';
}

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
$this->file = $file;
// check if we have an old image path
if (isset($this->path)) {
// store the old name to delete after the update
$this->temp = $this->path;
$this->path = null;
} else {
$this->path = 'initial';
}
}
 */
/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->path;
        $this->path = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
    }
}
/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // check if we have an old image
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        // delete the old image
        unlink($this->temp);
        // clear the temp image path
        $this->temp = null;
    }

    // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
    // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
    // which the UploadedFile move() method does
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
    );

    $this->setFile(null);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function storeFilenameForRemove()
{
    $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        unlink($this->temp);
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $time
 */
public function setTime($time)
{
    $this->time = $time;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getTime()
{
    return $this->time;
}





/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @return Email
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
  }
}
```

Hope one of those genious outhere bring back the light to my path!
Thanks and bless in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check with dump() if $city and $product are strings not class or array.

```
   $city = $email->setCity($form->get('city')->getData());       
   $product =$email->setProduct($form->get('product')->getData());
```

Maybe need like this

```
  $city = $form->get('city')->getData();       
  $product =$form->get('product')->getData();

  $email->setCity($city);       
  $email->setProduct($product);
```

Comment: Seems it's getting closer to a solution, but now I got this new error:Notice: Array to string conversion.                                                                                                                                                                                                                More detailed in the Logs:CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Array to string conversion" at C:\wamp\www\Quotera\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 120

Comment: if you have symfony >2.3 better use $form->handleRequest($request);
dump( $email)  after form is valid maybe  you do not need to set all variables second time like  $form->get('city')->getData(). maybe whey already are in $email.

By your error seems like $city or $product are not strings but arrays. show me Email entity or dump of $city and $product variable.

Comment: After I submitted the form I got back from var_dump($email) :   private 'product' => string 'Shirts, pants, shoes, underwear' (length=31)
  private 'city' => string 'Berlin' (length=6)
...but here is the challenge! In property 'emailTo',  is an empty array: (See below)
  private 'emailTo' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'email' => 
            array (size=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'email' => 
            array (size=1)
            
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'email' => 
            array (size=1)

Comment: And the error message is Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: hard to help, post your EMAIL entity, then i can say where entity want string not array..
as i understand:
$city and $product are strings,
$emails are array(),
function sendEmailsToProviders() return array(),
$email->setEmailTo() i thin are are string,

so how return sendEmailsToProviders() you want to set in $email->setEmailTo() string ?